# mysql syntax on not equal many values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the right syntax for the following case?

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts AS p 
WHERE post_type = 'post' 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND ID <> 5616,1095,1357,271,2784,902
ORDER BY post_title DESC
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Instead of `<>` , you can use `NOT IN (5616,1095...)`

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts AS p 
WHERE post_type = 'post' 
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND ID NOT IN (5616,1095,1357,271,2784,902)
ORDER BY post_title DESC
```

Comment: Beat me by 22 seconds. :-) +1, and deleting my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `<>` operator compares a single left and right argument to see if they are not equal. In your case you have one left hand argument that needs to be checked (I assume) to see if the `ID` is none of the values on the right. Therefore you should use `ID NOT IN (5616,1095,1357,271,2784,902)`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts AS p WHERE post_type = 'post' 
AND post_status = 'publish' AND 
ID NOT IN (5616,1095,1357,271,2784,902) ORDER BY post_title DESC
```