# Populating checkbox from server side data using 2 loops

Tags: php, arrays, database, checkbox

I have a need to check the checkboxes which values are available in the database, with that i has to display additional options avaialable also. 
I was trying, as i am using two loops it's repeating the same set of checkboxes and check differnt values in each instance.
I need to check the appropriate checkboxes in first loop itself. Is there any way to achieve this 
The following was my output
[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsenZ.png)

Following is the code i am using

```
$sid;//Retrived from DB
$iDLst=array();
$sql1 = "SELECT
`id1`
FROM `tbl1` 
where `tbl1_sid`='" . $sid . "'";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $iDLst[]=$row['id1'];
    }
}
foreach ($iDLst as $id){
    $sql2 = "SELECT
    `id`,
    `nme`
    FROM `tbl2`;
    ";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($rowC = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

            if (strpos($rowC['id'], $id) !== FALSE ) {
                echo ' <input value="' . $rowC['id'] . '" type="checkbox" name="upD[]" checked/>  <label>' . $rowC['nme'] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';


            }  else {
                echo ' <input value="' . $rowC['id'] . '" type="checkbox" name="upD[]" />  <label>' . $rowC['nme'] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**Note: I have changed to general code, There is no errors in code. I am getting the display. I need the solution regarding the logic part...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way after some research.
The way i am doing is only half part.
Following code will do the work addition to the provided code.

```
//Print the checkbox with checeked for the values in array
foreach ($iDLst as $id){
    $sql2 = "SELECT
    `id`,
    `nme`
    FROM `tbl2`;
    ";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($rowC = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {                                                                             
            echo ' <input value="' . $rowC['id'] . '" type="checkbox" name="upD[]" checked/>  <label>' . $rowC['nme'] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';                                             
              }
        }
    }
    //Print the checkbox without checeked for the values Not in array
    $sql3 = "$sql2 = "SELECT
    `id`,
    `nme`
    FROM `tbl2` where id NOT IN (" . implode(',', array_map('intval', $iDLst)) . ");    ";

    $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
    if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
             while ($rowC = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {                                               

             echo ' <input value="' . $rowC['id'] . '" type="checkbox" name="upD[]"/>  <label>' . $rowC['nme'] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>'; 

            }
    }
```

the following questions lead me the way to do this
[MySQL PHP - SELECT WHERE id = array()? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476146/mysql-php-select-where-id-array)

[mysql syntax on not equal many values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111451/mysql-syntax-on-not-equal-many-values)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace this:

```
if (strpos($rowC['id'], $id) !== FALSE ) {
                echo ' <input value="' . $rowC['id'] . '" type="checkbox" name="upD[]" checked/>  <label>' . $rowC['nme'] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';


            }  else {
                echo ' <input value="' . $rowC['id'] . '" type="checkbox" name="upD[]" />  <label>' . $rowC['nme'] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';
            }
```

with this:

```
echo ' <input value="' . $rowC['id'] . '" type="checkbox" name="upD[]" ' . strpos($rowC['id'], $id) ? 'checked ' : '' . '/>  <label>' . $rowC['nme'] . ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';
```

It's a ternary statement that says if strpos($rowC['id'], $id) evaluates true, 'checked ' will be in the enclosing `echo` statement, otherwise '' will be in the enclosing `echo` statement.

Comment: I don't see where `$id` is being set.

Comment: its in foreach loop

Comment: I see...do you know about MySQL JOIN? It looks like you could structure this way more simply by just joining the 2 tables in one query...

Comment: yap, that might work. I didn't think about that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have found a solution, check that out... @jcorry