# Automating a MySQL query to create a list

Tags: php, mysql

Instead of showing a list to the user of all the available properties that there are, I'm trying to show them all the properties that they have not already saved to their account. I record in a table on the database which properties the user has saved, I record this by the `id` of the property and the user's `id`.

So i would like to write a query like

`$query = "SELECT * FROM propertys WHERE id != 1 or 3";`

This would then select the property with an `id` of 2, and display it to the user, instead of a list of 1 and 2 and 3 where they have already seen and saved 1 and 3.

**The Problem**

This query written above does not seem to work. It still displays all the properties, which im not sure as why.

---

**EDIT:**

**The Actual Problem**

Now it wont display the properties that are left over. The query above doesnt display property 1 or 3, which is intented, but now also doesnt display property 2.

Comment: You need to include the column with each comparison. `$query = "SELECT * FROM propertys WHERE id != 1 and id != 3` or use `not in`. `$query = "SELECT * FROM propertys WHERE id no in (1,3)"`

Comment: I'm not sure you have written the right syntax sir, please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156979/sql-where-condition-not-equal-to

Comment: My second query has a typo, `$query = "SELECT * FROM propertys WHERE id not in (1,3)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer at least. From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111451/mysql-syntax-on-not-equal-many-values) There problem was trying to have the write syntax for multiple exclusions. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how SQL works.  You're trying to use PHP "not equal" inside a SQL statement.  You'll have to use the correct SQL for the database you are using.  It should look a lot more like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertys WHERE id <> 1 OR id <> 3"
```

or this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM propertys WHERE id NOT LIKE 1 OR id NOT LIKE 3"
```

Comment: `id <> 1 OR id <> 3` is the wrong logic, the `not 1` will bring back 3 and the `not 3` will bring back `1`. You need `and`. The `!=` also would work, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/104245/1 (although I'm not sure how compatible that is, I tend to use the `<>`).

Comment: @chris85 Was just about the write the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I actually found I could use, NOT IN (1, 2) and it worked! Thank you for the help though.

Comment: `!=` is a valid MySQL 'not equal' sign.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Answer (score 0):

If I had a row source for properties that are available values 1, 2 and 3 as stated in the question), e.g.

```
 property
 id  name
 --  -------
  1  foo
  2  fi
  3  fo
  4  fum
```

And I had a second table that contained rows for the properties that are "assigned" to each user, ... each row represents a property assigned to a user, and a "missing" row represents a property that isn't assigned, e.g.

```
 user_assigned_property
 user_name  property_id 
 -------    -----------
 jack       1
 jack       3
 giant      3
 giant      4
```

I would probably use an anti-join pattern: return all rows from property, with an outer join to the assigned properties, and a condition in the where clause to exclude all rows where there was a match

We expect this:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.name
  FROM property p 
  LEFT
  JOIN user_assigned_property a
    ON a.property_id = p.id
   AND a.user_name = 'jack'
 WHERE a.property_id IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY p.id
```

to return:

```
id  name
--  ----
 2  fi
 4  fum
```